# traverse matrix maze in 8 directions

Tags: algorithm, recursion

> You are given a matrix with 1s and 0s, where 0 represents free path and 1 represents blocked area. You can move in any of the 8 directions. Find the shortest path from source to destination.

The solution i was able to come up with, where `dp[i,j]` stores minimum distance from starting vertex:

```
recursion(int i, int j , int sum)
{

  if(!issafe(i,j) || isvisited[i,j]) // within bounds
  return ;

  if(matrix(i,j)==0)//blocked
  return ;

  isvisited[i,j]=true;

  dp[i,j] = min(dp[i,j] , sum);
  // directions have usual meaning

  recursion(east ,sum+1);  // i , j+1
  recursion(north , sum+1);  //i-1 , j
  recursion(west , sum+1);
  recursion(south , sum+1);
  recursion(north-east , sum+1);
  recursion(north-west , sum+1);
  recursion(south-east , sum+1);
  recursion(south-west , sum+1);

  isvisited[i,j]=false;

return;
}
```

now my doubt is that suppose we can reach [i,j] from 8 positions. As soon as I reach it from position 1, say min. path is x units, I recursively check for its neighbours straight away . Now, I come from path 2 and find that min. path (previously x) is now y not x, and now again recursively check. So, I have done extra calculations at step 1 which are not required. Is there any method by which I recursively check neighbours only after I find the min. path(reachable from all 8 positions) at current cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [shortest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path) in a non weighted graph, which is solveable by a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

In here your graph is `G=(V,E)` where

- `V = { all cells in the matrix}`
- `E= { (v1,v2) | can move from cell v1 to cell v2 }`

Note that your approach is a variation of [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), using additional data [the `dp` array]

---

More advanced approaches are [bi-directional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search) search or [A* algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) (with [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) as heuristic function).

---

bfs pseudo-code:

```
BFS(source,destination):
  visited <- {} //empty dictionary
  queue <- new queue
  queue.add (source)
  visited.add(source,null)
  while (! queue.isEmpty()):
      v <- queue.pop()
      if v == destination:
         return getPath(visited, v)
      for each edge (v,u):
         if u is not a key in visited:
             visited.add(u,v)
             queue.add(u)

getPath(visited,v):
   list <- new linked list
   while (v != null):
      list.addFirst(v)
      v <- visited.get(v)
   return list
```

Time complexity of this solution is `O(min{|V|,8^d})` - where `d` is length of the shortest path, and `|V|` is number of cells in the matrix.